How to create a BLAST local protein database without getting the error 'BLAST Database error: Database memory map file error'
I am trying to use psi-blast on a local database and keep getting errors.  I think that the errors that I am getting may be a result of the blast database not being created properly because when I create the database using the commmand:
makeblastdb -in smallmodified_scop_fa_represeq_lib_latest.fa -dbtype prot -out SCOPFAMBLAST_local_db

I get the following output:
Building a new DB, current time: 07/29/2024 19:24:58
New DB name:   C:\Users\realt\OneDrive\Documents\Biology Projects\BioInfoDATABASES\SCOPFABLASTDF\SCOPFAMBLAST_local_db
New DB title:  smallmodified_scop_fa_represeq_lib_latest.fa
Sequence type: Protein
Keep MBits: T
Maximum file size: 3000000000B
Adding sequences from FASTA; added 154 sequences in 0.0448847 seconds.


BLAST Database error: Database memory map file error

I tried ignoring the error and running a psi-blast script on the database anyway but I keep getting errors there to.  Therefore, I want to solve this problem first, verify that my database is good and then move on to running the psi-blast script.
Using the following input as a fasta file and the command above should reproduce the problem:
>8072807_Q7UJS6_4003632
NERILLVDDDYSLLNTLKRNLSFDFEVTTCESGPEALACIKKSDPFSVIMVDMRMPGMEGTEVIQKARLISPNSVYLMLTGNQDLTTAMEAVNEGQVFRFLNKPCQMSDIKAAINAGIKQYDLVTSKEELLKKT
>8072797_O51615_4003632
SKPRGINYDTGIPFNVLIVDDSVFTVKQLTQIFTSEGFNIIDTAADGEEAVIKYKNHYPNIDIVTLDITMPKMDGITCLSNIMEFDKNARVIMISALGKEQLVKDCLIKGAKTFIVKPLDRAKVLQRVMSVFVK
>8022848_2OP5_A_4001912
TDETAFLNSLFMDFTSENELELFLKSLDEVWSEDLYSRLSAAGLIRHVISKVWNKEQHRISMVFEYDSKEGYQKCQEIIDKEFGITLKEKLKKFVFKIHNNRGVVVSEFIRS
>8107333_Q9HB45_4007725
FSTVKIIYTVGHSISIVALFVAITILVALRRLHCPRNYVHTQLFTTFILKAGAVFLKDAALFHSDDTDHCSFSTVLCKVSVAASHFATMTNFSWLLAEAVYLNCLLASTSPSSRRAFWWLVLAGWGLPVLFTGTWVSCKLAFEDIACWDLDDTSPYWWIIKGPIVLSVGVNFGLFLNIIRILVRKLEPAQGSLHTQSQYWRLSKSTLFLIPLFGIHYIIFNFLPDNAGLGIRLPLELGLGSFQGFIVAILYCFLNQEVRTEISRKW
>8097333_B8NBN5_4000755
PTNPLTLIVATTPIPTREKTLLGIGLNGTLPWPRIKADMSFFARVTTRPPRPGTTNAMIMGRKTYDSVPKSLRPLGKRINVIVTRDVEGVSKRVAEELKEKRAKMAAAAAAATSAGENKEEGPITDAIVSSGLEAALEDVEEKFKGGLGSVFVIGGAEIYATALGLGGDRPVRIVMTNVEKKGVDGEKAVFECDTFFPIDEELLMEKGWRKVSAEEVTEWVGEPVSGEWKDEGEVRIQMVGYERV
>8047374_P29033_4005615
DWGTLQTILGGVNKHSTSIGKIWLTVLFIFRIMILVVAAKEVWGDEQADFVCNTLQPGCKNVCYDHYFPISHIRLWALQLIFVSTPALLVAMHVAYRRHEKKRKFIKGEIKSEFKDIEEIKTQKVRIEGSLWWTYTSSIFFRVIFEAAFMYVFYVMYDGFSMQRLVKCNAWPCPNTVDCFVSRPTEKTVFTVFMIAVSGICILLNVTELCYLLIRY
>8022849_Q9I4A4_4000237
MASYAELFDIGEDFAAFVGHGLATEQGAVARFRQKLESNGLPSALTERLQRIERRYRLLVAGEMWCPDCQINLAALDFAQRLQPNIELAIISKGRAEDDLRQRLALERIAIPLVLVLDEEFNLLGRFVERPQAVLDGGPQALAAYKAGDYLEHAIGDVLAIIEGAA
>8022850_Q837R1_4000595
MDISVIDATKVNTETGLHIGESNAPVKMIEFINVRCPYCRKWFEESEELLAQSVKSGKVERIIKLFDKEKESLQRGNVMHHYIDYSAPEQALSALHKMFATQDEWGNLTLEEVATYAEKNLGLKEQKDATLVSAVIAEANAAHIQFVPTIIIGEYIFDESVTEEELRGYIEK
>8072809_A3DCZ0_4003632
AKILVIDDESTILQNIKFLLEIDGNEVLTASSSTEGLRIFTENCNSIDVVITDMKMPKLSGMDILREIKKITPHMAVIILTGHGDLDNAILAMKEGAFEYLRKPVTAQDLSIAINNAINRKKLLM
>8072799_A0A0H3AMJ9_4003632
NKNMKILIVDDFSTMRRIVKNLLRDLGFNNTQEADDGLTALPMLKKGDFDFVVTDWNMPGMQGIDLLKNIRADEELKHLPVLMITAEAKREQIIEAAQAGVNGYIVKPFTAATLKEKLDKIFE

How can I create the blast database correctly and without error using data like the fasta data above?

i had the same error and the command only worked when the folders names where all without spaces on their names. if still doesnt work, maybe try renaming all the folders without _ or any other character that isnt letters
